# angular js on enter prevent submit

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

I am new to angular js and I am developing a form which has many input fields and two buttons- one for cancel and another one for submitting the form.

i am having a ng-submit="" on the form tag to recognize if the form is submitted and show some error messages.

Problem i am facing is when i click on enter 'cancel' button is triggered. How do i prevent this?
I tried adding type=input on the button but it does not work.

```
<button type="button" ng-click="function">Cancel</button>
```

I cannot change the button tag to input tag as i am applying some styles and i am losing them if i change the tag.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

below is the code for button.

```
<div class="button-group-right" style="width:49%; float:left">
        <button  class="btn btn-large btn-tertiary btn-right" ng-click="subnmitPage()">
        <span class="btn-text">
        <span class="btn-text-container">Submit</span>
        </span>
        <span class="btn-icon">
        <i class="navigateright button-icon"></i>
        </span>
        </button>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show us the code used for `Enter` button

Comment: just added the code in the UPDATE section

Comment: both are completely same. i will edit it now

Comment: Just a thought. You can set `tabindex = 1' for  submit and `tabindex = 2` for cancel button in the dom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i fixed it by adding $event in my function and saying preventDefault().
code below.

in html:

```
 <button ng-click="subnmitPage($event)"/>
```

and in controller

```
$scope.subnmitPage=function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
}
```